# Apache .conf file ignored

Tags: apache-2.4, apache2, mpm-prefork

I'm running Apache Apache/2.4.25 (Amazon) using prefork and I'm trying to adjust ServerLimit and MaxRequestWorkers. I'm using the following settings:

`<IfModule prefork.c>
   ServerLimit 40
   MaxRequestWorkers 40
</IfModule>`

The problem is that if I add these settings in /etc/http/conf.d/prefork.conf, they are ignored despite the general /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf having the following directive set:

`IncludeOptional conf.d/*.conf`

Other configuration files present in conf.d/ seem to be parsed but not this one. So, the only way I could adjust the limits is by editing /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf directly and placing the above. Why are the values not read from a conf.d/*.conf file? Has anyone else ran into this issue? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Just yesterday I had the same issue. Eventually it's about the position when it is included. It seemed like I couldn't change the StartServers setting for mpm-worker. Interestingly enough my other settings in the same file were definitely applied...dunno yet but will continue testing on Monday...

Answer (score 1):

Did you check the permissions of `/etc/http/conf.d/prefork.conf`. If you created the file as `root` or another user and the permissions aren't `o+r`, apache user might not be able to read the file.

This would probably be visible in server logs.

Another problem might be that if the `ServerRoot` is not set to `/etc/http/`, the [IncludeOptional](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#include) would not work. You can try setting it to a full path:

```
IncludeOptional /etc/http/conf.d/*.conf
```

Comment: I did check the permissions, they were 644. I even set the owner to apache.apache. The server root is set to /etc/httpd indeed.

Comment: Full path got it working for me. Thanks!